# How to use angular scope variable into @string.Concat() of MVC cshtml page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to use angular scope variable in anchor tag **ng-click** as param[that param should be used with @string.Concat] in cshtml page like below.

```
              <a href="#" 
  ng-click="GetName('@string.Concat("Selected name:",name)')"> {{name}} </a>
```

```js
var personApp = angular.module('personApp', []);
personApp.controller('personController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.GetName = function(name){
      alert(name);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body ng-app="personApp">
    <h1>Scope</h1>
    <div  ng-controller="personController" ng-init="names=['John Doe', 'Mary Jane', 'Bob Parker']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names">
              <a href="#" 
  ng-click="GetName('@string.Concat("Selected name:",name)')"> {{name}} </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@string.Concat` is C# code and it gets executed on the server when razor tries to render the page. At that time your angular code/variable is not even available ! Razor will send the output of it's execution (of the C# code in the view) to the browser which is plain html markup. Then only your angular code will be executed. So you cannot mix client side js varibale to c# code like that.

The best you can do is to simply pass the `name` variable which is your client side js variable.

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names">
    <a href="#" ng-click="GetName(name)"> {{name}} </a>
</li>
```